# EntityFramework 6 One To One Mapping with shared key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

As an example I had following existing table, which i cannot change
Contacts - [ID, Name, Age] (Primary Key: ID)

No i want to extend the functionality using following extension table

Details - [ID, Address, Phone] (Primary Key:ID, Foreign Key: ID)

Note that Details.Id is primary key as well as foreign key (referencing Contacts.Id)

My domain model is

```
Contact
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public int Age {get;set;}
 public Details Details {get;set;}
}

Details
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Address {get;set;}
 public string Phone {get;set;}
}
```

How do i write mapping for this in entity framework 6

Comment: Define a composite key.

Comment: I am new to EF, please elaborate with some example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [composite key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Composite) this way:

```
public class Details
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Contact")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Details Details { get; set; } 
}
```

Now Details's ID is a primary key as well as foreign key

Comment: You explicitly add the `Contact` property to `Details` while it's missing in the OP's code. What if that's what the OP wants (don't want to expose the navigation property `Contact`)?

Comment: @Sirwan
I am sorry i did not mention earlier, i am trying to do it via fluent API rather than attribute decoration. i will try it with attributes but if you know to do the same in fluent API, please give an example of how to specify foreign key with fluent API.

Comment: @Hopeless even though i don't have any need to expose navigation property in details, i have tried it and does not work. main problem i am getting in any case is that its looking for "Contact_ID" rather than "ID", only if i knew how to override foreign key name

Comment: @Gurpreet do you mean you tried this exact code (with attribute) but it did not work? So let the owner explain it.

Comment: I have tried my answer and it works. Do you need this functionality with fluent API? and without navigation property?

Comment: Yes please, that would be wonderful, for now i have continued with your suggestion of using attribute